# Difference between SQL procedure and CLR procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlclr

What is the difference between a simple SQL procedure and a CLR procedure?
Which one is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CLR procedure is written in a .NET language and the assembly must be integrated with SQL Server. A Stored Procedure is written in T-SQL.

Unless you need to do something "secret" or something that requires support from the OS (like TCP communication for example), I'd always go for the "normal" Stored Procedure, as it can be maintained much easier than a CLR procedure.

Comment: Ya you are write and sp_helptext doesn't work with CLR it shows rather only the schema of the procedure so that secret thing you are talking about is preserved whereas,for stored procedure it works